# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DateField' and 'DateField'

Tags: django, django-models, model, date-formatting

I am working on creating a contract model with Django and I came cross on how to get the time duration from the start_date to the end_date??

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField(end_date - start_date) # how get the duration by hours
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate a field in your model one good approach is to do that in an overridden save method.

Substracting one datetime from another results in a timedelta object. I am converting this here into seconds, assuming that is what you wanted.

```py
class Contract(models.Model):
    ...
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.duration = (self.end_date - self.start_date).total_seconds()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise *not* to store this in a field: several ORM queries like for example [**`.update(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) circumvent the [**`.save(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save), so that means that there are ways to update the `start_date`, or `end_date` *without* the `duration` being updated properly.

You can add a property that will simply determine the duration when necessary, indeed:

```
from datetime import timedelta

class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def duration(self):
        return (self.end_date - self.start_date) // timedelta(hours=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```